# How do I concatenate integer binary values in an array in C?

Tags: c, binary, embedded, hex

I'm writing a embedded systems program that receives 24-bit data from an external ADC over SPI and stores the data in an integer array. That part is working. In order for the data to be useful, I need to concatenate each byte in either binary or hexadecimal form and divide by 0x7FFFFFF. This is where I'm running into trouble. For example, I might receive a data array over SPI that looks like this:

```
data_buffer = { 24 , 17 , 140 };
```

aka

```
data_buffer = { 0b00011000 , 0b00010001 , 0b10001100 };
```

aka

```
data_buffer = { 0x18 , 0x11 , 0x8C };
```

What I need to do with this value is concatenate each element to get something like this:

```
data_value = 0x18118C
```

And then divide that value by 0x7FFFFF in order for it to be useful in my program. In this example the value I'd like to end up with is 0x18118C/0x7FFFFF = 0.188

How would I go about doing this?

I'm sorry I haven't provided more code, I honestly have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combining three bytes into one 24-bit (actually 32-bit) value is a straightforward application of C's bitwise operators.
Here it is in a verbose, "longhand" form:

```
unsigned char data_buffer[] = { 24 , 17 , 140 };

unsigned long int data_value = 0;
data_value |= data_buffer[0];
data_value <<= 8;
data_value |= data_buffer[1];
data_value <<= 8;
data_value |= data_buffer[2];
```

I would probably write it in a more compact form:

```
unsigned long int data_value = 0;
data_value |= data_buffer[0];
data_value = (data_value << 8) | data_buffer[1];
data_value = (data_value << 8) | data_buffer[2];
```

Or you can do it in the other order, so to speak:

```
unsigned long int data_value = 0;
data_value |= (unsigned long)data_buffer[0] << 16;
data_value |= data_buffer[1] << 8;
data_value |= data_buffer[2];
```

(Here you need an extra cast, though, in case you're on a 16-bit processor, where plain `data_buffer[0] << 16` would shift all the bits away and lose them.)

Or you could do it all at once:

```
unsigned long int data_value =
    ((unsigned long)data_buffer[0] << 16) |
                   (data_buffer[1] << 8) |
                    data_buffer[2];
```

In any case, you can then do the division you want:

```
float float_value = (float)data_value / 0x7FFFFF;
```

(You might want to use `double` instead of `float`.  Or depending on the limitations of your embedded environment, you may not wish to use straightforward floating-point like this at all; you didn't say.)

When I print these, I get the values you requested:

```
printf("data_value = %#lX, float_value = %f\n", data_value, float_value);
```

yields:

```
data_value = 0X18118C, float_value = 0.188036
```

---

Addendum: One thing I forgot to mention is that for these techniques to work correctly, it's typically *really important* that your input data, i.e. the `data_buffer` array in your example, be of type `unsigned char`.  If it's not -- for example if it's plain `char`, which is signed on most machines -- you typically end up having debilitating sign extension problems.  For example, your value 140 is the hex number `0x8c`, as you know, but interpreted as a *signed* 8-bit number, it's -116.  And when it participates in an expression with other integers, it typically gets sign-extended to `0xff8c` or `0xffffff8c`, which is of course not what you want at all.  (You can work around this with extra masks of `& 0xff`, as suggested in SteveB's answer, but that's a nuisance.  Much more straightforward to use `unsigned char`.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve, it has been extremely helpful. The type of the array is 'static uint8_t' , I don't have much flexibility in changing this type since I'm using a function from some example code. Will this type work as well?

Comment: Yes, `uint8_t` is unsigned, and is basically equivalent to `unsigned char`, and should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to shift the values into an integer of the correct size. In your example:

```
int data_value = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    data_value = data_value << 8;
    data_value |= data[i] & 0xff;    // Makes sure you are only adding 8 bits
}
```

You can adapt that as necessary for varying array sizes. You will just need to make sure that data_value is big enough to hold everything. Since you are working with 24 bits of data, a 32 bit integer will work. Then you will assign data_value to a floating point value and do your division.

```
double data_double = data_value;
double final_value = data_double / 8388607.0
```

You need to use floating point value of 0x7FFFFF to avoid the integer truncation.

Comment: Not knowing the length of `int` on the target in question, it would be safer and appropriate to use `int32_t` or `uint32_t`.

Comment: @Clifford - OP said he was working with 24 bits of data and he is dividing by a 32 bit number. Knowing that, int on that platform is at least 32 bits. If it wasn't, int32_t and uint32_t would not be supported anyway. Since he is using 24 bits of data, whether or not the integer result is signed is irrelevant. My solution will work just fine. Please read the question and the answer completely before you downvote it.

Comment: but we do not know that int is 32 bits, and int being 16 bits does not preclude the availability of a 32 bit type. The use of stdint type avoids the need to know whether the underlying type needs to be int or long int. I would not have dreamed of downvoting this - merely suggesting an improvement. Your comment however is alarmingly wrong. Yes in this case signed or unsigned makes no difference (assuming it is not 24 bit 2&#39;s complement which will require additional handling) - that is why I suggested either.

Comment: Apologies @Clifford. I assumed you downvoted it, sorry.